# Acetone-resistant clear plastic

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, stability, solvents, plastics

Is there a plastic that's clear, acetone resistant, and ideally sold in sheet stock that's ~1/8" or 1/4" thick?  Both acrylic and polycarbonate are out, they turn cloudy on contact with acetone.  I tried a piece of PETG and it was better, but still turned fairly cloudy after a few seconds.  I don't need continuous service, but I need it to still look decent if it gets wiped down with acetone.

Comment: Would glass work? If you want the more durable plastic properties, maybe laminate glass onto acrylic/polycarb? If your piece only needs to be tablet-sized, buying a glass tablet screen protector is super cheap. For something bigger, could epoxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only real option for this is a clear plastic sheet that's had a chemical resistant thin film applied to the faces.  One commercially available example is Makrolon AR2, it's polycarbonate with some proprietary coating that's listed as having >24hrs resistance to acetone and a few other chemicals.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Palstics International's Chemical Resistance Chart](https://www.plasticsintl.com/chemical-resistance-chart), the A-rated plastics (no solvent attack) towards acetone are:

- [ECTFE (Halar®)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECTFE): transparent films available
- [Fluorosint® PTFE](https://www.aetnaplastics.com/products/d/Fluorosint): white
- [HDPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-density_polyethylene): transparent films available
- [Nylon®, Type 6/6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon_66): white
- [PP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polypropylene): clear sheets available
- [PPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphenylene_sulfide): opaque white
- [PTFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene): white

Among these, polypropylene appears to be the only plastic that satisfies all criteria.

Comment: +1 iPP can be made to crystallise in structures smaller than optical wavelenght. Its done with comonomer contents and/or tacticity defects in a small percent range and/or a lot of nucleating agents.

Comment: From what I can tell, clear polypropylene is biaxially oriented polypropylene, it looks like it gets stretched in 2 directions while being formed.  I think this process is mostly used for thinner packaging material, something a few mil thick.  I wasn't able to find anything in sheet form that's an 1/8" or 1/4" thick.

Comment: @Shawn You are correct, getting optically clear or even just transparent PP 1/8" sheet isn't trivial. If semi-transparent white PP sheet isn't an option, then one should probably look further for less common proprietary plastics.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, cast your own sheet (or straight your close-to-final piece) using a mold from a chemical resistant 2 part epoxy. Usually, [difunctional or polyfunctional amine hardeners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy#Amines) confer chemical/temperature resistance, causing a polymerization in a 3D cross-linked network (it also means saying goodbye to thermoplasticity).

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=chemical+resistant+epoxy+clear) - customize it for the TLD/geo area you live in.

Example of [a result](https://www.epoxysupplies.com.au/APC-Epoxy-Range/EPO100C/epoxy-resin-clear-3L-epoxy-supplies) that works for me (haven't use it yet, but I had a chat with a sale representative and confirmed that it maintains its clear/mechanical resistance when using with acetone *after* the cure).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a plastic material that is clear, acetone-resistant, and available in sheet stock around 1/8" or 1/4" thickness, especially in the context of epoxy hardeners. In this case, you might consider using PTFE (polytetrafluoroethylene), commonly known as Teflon. PTFE is known for its chemical resistance, including resistance to acetone. It's transparent, maintains clarity, and is available in various thicknesses, including sheets.

When working with epoxy hardeners like used in [epoxy flooring](https://coasttocountryspecialisedcoatings.com/), having a clear, acetone-resistant barrier like PTFE can be essential for maintaining a clean and visible workspace. Ensure to check specific product specifications and compatibility before use.

Best of luck with your project!